# Spring Cloud - ZUUL API Gateway - uploading and downloading a csv (or any format) file?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-gateway

Using Spring Boot, I have tested the method described [here](https://codeburst.io/returning-csv-content-from-an-api-in-spring-boot-63ea82bbcf0f) to download a csv file by hitting the backend api.
Here the flow is simple: `browser` <--request/response--> `backend api` and the response headers (`headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + csvFileName);`) set by the backend api are directly interpreted by the `browser` and so it's straight forward.

But in my actual production environment, I have an API Gateway (ZUUL in my case) between browser and backend api. And I am not sure if the above approach will work when the request/response goes through api-gateway.

Can `api-gateway`'s interpret the response headers and pass the same to the client i.e browser along with the data. Or any additional configuration is required.

Similarly does file uploads going through `api-gateway` to backend server need any additional consideration.

Comment: Only for large files

Comment: @spencergibb - +1. You mean its gonna work with file upload and file download with out issues even with api-gateway in-between. cool!! tx.

Comment: @samshers Spring Cloud Netflix Zuul has been out of support for some time now. We strongly recommend switching to Spring Cloud Gateway instead.

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek - noted down your point.